# GVim slow to refocus

Tags: windows, vim

I am using Vim and GVim on a Win32 platform (alas, Windows is against my nature, but it's a work machine). I have noticed in GVim that when it returns to focus (either using the mouse, or via ALT+TAB) there is a brief lag of 2-3 seconds before the cursor resumes flashing and it becomes usable. I definitely do not experience this in when running Vim from the console. I have not it experienced on Linux boxes either, but then I do not edit such long files on my home machine.

Previously I also experienced the slow behaviour when switching between splits within a GVim session (using `<c-w><c-w>`). Some of the files I edit can be very long, and I have a custom statusline which requires some processing, and GVim was apparently recalculating the highlighting, folding and statusline every time. I was able to avoid that by setting

```
set eventignore=BufEnter,WinEnter,BufWinEnter
```

But I still have the problems when the GVim window itself regains focus. Adding `set eventignore+=FocusGained` makes no difference. Is there any way to persuade GVim to return to focus more smoothly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Define "long"/"very long"? Are we talking log files of a couple of Gb here, or ... ? Does "filetype syntax off" does anything noticeable?

Comment: @Idigas: the delay is noticable even with files with only ~2000 lines, so presumably that is not the issue. Turning fileype syntax off has no effect, nor does disabling folding. I tried writing a vim logifile (`gvim -V12vimlog`), but nothing is logged until I move the cursor, by which time the lag is over.

Comment: Could you uplaod your _vimrc somewhere? I'm using the same platform, and have no such problems.

Comment: Sadly I don't think that would help, because my Vim customisations  total more than 4000 lines. It's useful to know that it's not a Windows problem, so I will now attempt to systematically debug my Vimscript. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 4k lines?! Ever thought about splitting it up a bit? In any case, sorry I couldn't help more. I can't say whether it's a Windows or gVim problem, just that I'm not having it. I know Vim can get slow when for example editing large HTML files due to regex parsing, but turning syntax off in those cases, usually help.

Comment: Check for example do you have some augroups/mappings that are duplicates and stuff like that. Just a thought ...

Comment: Most of it is in a separate plugin script which I suspect is responsible. But it seems strange that nothing is logged by `gvim -V12log` during the pause...

Comment: Maybe if you could tell something about that script then? I usually don't like to set up theories without any facts known.

Comment: The *very* first thing to try would be with an empty `_vimrc` file. Then you can either (a) eliminate that (or the plugins you're loading) as a possible problem, or (b) it is the problem, so divide and conquer.

Comment: @GregHewgill - Good idea. _Prince - with "gvim -u none"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have any of the following lines on a network drive (in a corporate environment, the Home drive (My Documents etc.) is frequently on a fileserver...

- the file itself - this might not be fixable
- the swapfile (`:se noswap` to disable, `:se directory="C:\blabla"` to relocate)
- the `undofile` (`:se noundofile` to disable, `:se undodir="C:\blabla"` to relocate)

I explicitely moved all of these files to a local folder on my Win32 setup. (Hey, I'm also the guy known to mutilate the virus checker enough to disable on-access scanning just to speed things up a little).

Comment: Thanks, sehe, the file was indeed on a particularly slow network drive. I feel foolish for not realising that was the problem straight away...!